# How to measure cumulative execution time of code in a loop in Android?

Tags: java, android, profiling

With the use of the TimerLogger class, we can time code in a method like this

```
TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger(YOUR_TAG, "methodA");
// ... do some work A ... 
timings.addSplit("work A");
// ... do some work B ... 
timings.addSplit("work B");
// ... do some work C ... 
timings.addSplit("work C");
timings.dumpToLog();
```

Is there a way to time the total time spent executing code (to keep it simple one line) in a loop, over the loops execution?
e.g. for a loop of 100,000 iterations 400ms was spent executing line x and 500ms was spent executing line y

```
public void foo() {
    for () {
        // start
        code to execute
        // end
        // accumulate
    }
}
```